Latex .cls file to Lyx module/layout conversion, The Legrand Orange Book
I am in the process of book writing for school students and started using LYX. Earlier I used Libre Office. While surfing, I came across legrand-orange-book and was impressed with the formatting for various environments.
However, the template/source code is for latex only. There is no lyx layout or module available. I would like to recreate few environment in lyx and being newbie, I need some working code to understand the logics. One example being "Exercise" environment from AMSTheorem. The following is the code for this environment extracted from legrand orange book.
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amssymb, amsthm} % For math equations, theorems, symbols, etc
\usepackage{tikz}
\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{$\blacksquare$} % Redefine the QED symbol to be a filled square vs. the default unfilled square
\newtheorem{exerciseT}{Exercise}[chapter]
\RequirePackage[framemethod=default]{mdframed}
\definecolor{ocre}{RGB}{243, 102, 25} % Define the color used for highlighting throughout the book

% Exercise box
\newmdenv[
    skipabove=7pt, % Whitespace above box
    skipbelow=7pt, % Whitespace below box
    rightline=false, % Right line visible
    leftline=true, % Left line visible
    topline=false, % Top line visible
    bottomline=false, % Bottom line visible
    linecolor=ocre, % Line color
    linewidth=4pt, % Line width
    backgroundcolor=ocre!10, % Background color
    innerleftmargin=5pt, % Inside left margin width
    innerrightmargin=5pt, % Inside right margin width
    innertopmargin=5pt, % Inside top margin height
    innerbottommargin=5pt, % Inside bottom margin height
    leftmargin=0cm, % Outside left margin width
    rightmargin=0cm % Outside right margin width
]{eBox}

\newenvironment{exercise}{\begin{eBox}\begin{exerciseT}}{\hfill{\color{ocre}\tiny\ensuremath{\blacksquare}}\end{exerciseT}\end{eBox}}

The output in pdf looks like this:
extract from legrand orange book pdf output
So far, I am using the above code in preamble and using ctrl+L and typing tex codes inside LYX for achieving my result. Kindly someone point me to working codes/layout/module on bringing the "Exercise" environment in the side panel of LYX GUI to minimize the tex coding works. I shall use this code to create other environments like Example, Corollary, Problems, etc.
Thanks in Advance.
